# Split string on delimiter while ignoring substrings

Tags: python, string, split

Thanks for the help guys..
I have really weird case, I have list of strings in python.
When I split based on (,) I want 'split' to ignore the substring.

Ex:

```
string = "'test_1[off,on]hello', 200, 300"
#check 'test_1[off,on]hello' is a substring 
print string.split(',')
```

Actual op:

```
['test_1[off', 'on]hello', '200', '300']
```

Expected op:

```
['test_1[off,on]hello', '200', '300']
```

Can we explicitly ask split not worry about substring?
Or is there any other equivalent function in Python to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend regex's `re.split` here, it's a lot more flexible to patterns.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r',\s*(?!.*?])', string)
["'test_1[off,on]hello'", '200', '300']
```

---

**Details**

```
,       # comma
\s*     # whitespace (any number of chars)
(?!     # negative lookahead
.*?     # anything
]       # closing brace
)
```

The pattern will not split on a comma that is located inside `[...]`.

Comment: Cool Thanks.. For the people who would visit later I used this logic

Answer (score 1):

The output of your code is actually

```
["'test_1[off", "on]hello'", ' 200', ' 300']
```

(Note the space before 200 and 300.)

You can use this space to your advantage here:

```
string = "'test_1[off,on]hello', 200, 300"
print string.split(', ')
```

gives

```
["'test_1[off,on]hello'", '200', '300']
```

For a more general case I'm afraid you can't tell `split` to "ignore" a substring (at least I'm not aware of it). But you can do some easy post processing, or use regex...

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be:

```
my_string = "'test_1[off,on]hello', 200, 300"
my_substring = "'test_1[off,on]hello'"
temp = [s.split(',') for s in my_string.split(my_substring)] # Here you get a list of lists  [[''], ['', ' 200', ' 300']]
res = [s for l in temp for s in l + [my_substring ] if s][:-1] # we concat them, ignore the empty string generated by the split and add my_substring again
print res 
>> ["'test_1[off,on]hello'", ' 200', ' 300']
```